# How to allow duplicate entities on Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two entities and manytomany relations between them.

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="algo")
public class Algo{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int id;
   ...
   @ManyToMany
   protected List<DbMatch> matches = new ArrayList<DbMatch>();
   ...
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="matches")
public class DbMatch extends Match{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int mid;
   ....
```

When I try save `algo` with `dbmatches` list, but I got `Duplicate entry '90786' for key 'UK_auyvi1qkpdtaqrpuyv9je5rda'` on algo_matches table.

```
Table: algo_matches
Columns:
algo_id int(11)
matches_mid int(11)
```

How to store different `algo` objects but with possibility store duplicate matches on list?

e.g algo with algo_id 1 have match with match_id 1 and algo with algo_id 2 have match with match_id 1

indexes

> algo_matches
>   0
>   UK_auyvi1qkpdtaqrpuyv9je5rda
>   1
>   matches_mid
>   A
>   5125
>   NULL
>   NULL
>   BTREE
>   algo_matches
>   1
>   FK_h5utrptgjclq043weh6eks58g
>   1
>   algo_id
>   A
>   4
>   NULL
>   NULL
>   BTREE
>   algo_matches
>   1
>   matches_mid
>   1
>   matches_mid
>   A
>   5125
>   NULL
>   NULL
>   BTREE

I use this dao method for update algo object when add new match to list:

```
public void update(Algo a){
    try {           
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(a);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        session.clear();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the primary key fr `algo_matches`?

Comment: I guess u hv assigned keys to columns in algo_matches. Remove those.

Comment: I try get primary key using `SHOW KEYS FROM algo_matches WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'` but get empty table.

Comment: Also, its better idea to annotate accessors instead of fields.

Comment: I'd add a `algo_matches_id` primary key to the `algo_matches` table which is unique per row. Hibernate makes it difficult to use [composite keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) so it's best to avoid them.

Comment: @Forkmohit added dao to post

Comment: Remove unique key from matches_mid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop `UK_auyvi1qkpdtaqrpuyv9je5rda`  unique index from `algo_matches` table.